# How to make geth keep states for the last 10000 blocks instead of 128

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync, state-trie-pruning

If I understand it correctly, geth preserves states for the last 128 blocks and prunes states for all other blocks. I would like to keep states for a bigger number of last blocks, say 10000 blocks. Is it possible?

Thank you!

EDIT: [Suggested](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40648/full-node-sync-only-preserve-the-last-128-history-states) question isn't the same as mine. I was hoping I don't need to run a full fledged archive node to be able to see states for the last 10000 blocks. I'm certain I wouldn't need to get state for any block that is more than a week old

Comment: Hmm, no ideas? :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full node sync only preserve the last 128 history states](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40648/full-node-sync-only-preserve-the-last-128-history-states)

Comment: I was hoping I don't need to run a full fledged archive node. I need states for only 10000 last blocks (1 week worth of blocks).

Comment: IMO this is a different question.